# When does a spell end, exactly?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, duration

Let's say my character casts a spell as a swift action during his turn and this spell gives a bonus to all characters in a 30 ft. radius around him "until his next turn".

Is it the start or the end of my next turn? Or does it depend on when in my turn I cast it?

In other words, do I get the benetits twice or potentially not even once if I cast it at the end of my turn?

(This question comes from a player using [a martial maneuver from Path of War](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/path-of-war/disciplines-and-maneuvers/golden-lion-maneuvers/encouraging-roar) at the end of their own turn to buff their companions, but I guess it's valid for all spells and similar effects too, so I have generalized it.)

Comment: (The linked maneuver says *for 1 round.*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [PFSRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-The-Combat-Round):

> When the rules refer to a “full round”, they usually mean a span of time from a particular initiative count in one round to the same initiative count in the next round. **Effects that last a certain number of rounds end just before the same initiative count that they began on.**

So no matter when inside the player's turn they activated it, it would last until just before their turn starts next round.  As a swift action, though, they could use it at the start of their turn and get the benefit themselves in the same turn.

(Note that the maneuver you linked actually says "one round" for duration, both in the stat block and the text.)

Comment: The game is actually using its own jargon incorrectly here. When the rules refer to *1 or more rounds* the rules usually mean a span of time from a particular initiative count in one round to the same initiative count in the later rounds. The game uses the term *full round* to means something that occupies *only* a creature's own turn. (For example, a full attack does *not* start on the attacker's turn then conclude right before on the same initiative count next round, but the full attack—a full round action—happens entirely on the attacker's turn.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Actually, it's just that "full round" and "full round action" are totally different things.  A full found spans from the initiative count it starts on until just before that initiative count on the next round, but a "full round action" is contained to a single turn.  Note, though, that a full round action taken by a staggered character using the Begin Full Round Action action and the Complete Full Round Action action takes only one single initiative count longer than a full round to complete, which is probably a coincidence but funny to notice.

Comment: Pardon my overreaction. I don't *like* it, and the game should've used a word besides *full* twice, like in [Metamagic Feats](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats) where it says that "casting a metamagic version is a full-round action for a sorcerer or bard. (This isn’t the same as a 1-round casting time.)"

Comment: @HeyICanChan I see no overreaction, it's not intuitive at all and actually pretty annoying.

Answer (score 5):

The usage here is clear.

"Until" means once reached. So you would grant the bonus on the same turn you activated it, while others are taking their turn. As soon as its your turn in the imitative order again (having delayed still means your turn was reached so no infinite buffs), the bonus ends. Even if you are unable to act on your turn for whatever reason, it still ends.

Answer (score 0):

One round, as per your source.

> All allies within 30-ft. of the Golden Lion disciple gain a +2 morale bonus to attack and damage rolls for one round.

Therefore it ends once you start your next action which would be the start of your turn in the following round after the casting.

Alternatively this [thread](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2llv8?Duration-of-One-Round) on the Paizo forums seems to cover this question as well.

Comment: I believe that this is correct, but please provide evidence and a more explanatory answer that is easier to understand

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.